# c++ segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, error-handling

I really dont see where the segmentation error occured. Here is my code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

class isbn
{
    private:
        string *code;
        int digit;
        isbn *current, *next;

    public:

    //constructor
    isbn(): code(NULL), digit(0) { }

    //copy constructor
    isbn(const isbn &other):
        code(new string[other.digit]),
        digit(other.digit)
        {
        for(int i=0; i < digit; i++)    
            code[i] = other.code[i];
        }
    //destructor
    ~isbn()
    {
        if(digit>0) delete [] code;
    }
    //set up the private values 
    void setCode(char *temp, int num);
    void setDigit(const int &num);

    //return the value of the pointer character 
    const string &getCode(int num) const;
    const unsigned int getDigit() const;

    //assignment operator
    isbn operator = (const isbn &other)
    {
        code = new string[other.digit];
        digit = other.digit;
        for(int i=0; i < digit; i++)    
            code[i] = other.code[i];
        return *this;
    }
    //equal operator for a digit
    bool operator == (const isbn &other) const
    {
        return code == other.code;
    }

};

const string& isbn::getCode(int num) const
{
    return code[num];
}
const unsigned int isbn::getDigit() const
{
    return digit;
}
void isbn::setCode(char *temp, int num) 
{
    if (num<0 || num >= digit)
    {
        throw out_of_range("error occurred from setCode");
    }
    code[num] = temp;
}
void isbn::setDigit(const int &num)
{
    digit = num;
}

void extIsbn_in_file(list<isbn> &isbns, const string &filename)
{
    ifstream filein;
    filein.clear();
    filein.open(filename.c_str());
    if(!filein)
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file to read \n";
        exit(0);
    }
    cout << "\n file : " << filename << "\n";
    cout << "\n";

    char *contents;
    isbn aisbn;
    list<isbn>::iterator isbnitr;
    isbnitr = isbns.begin();
    int count = 0;

    while(!filein.eof())
    {
        filein.getline(contents, '\n');
        cout << contents << '\n';
        aisbn.setCode(contents, count);
        aisbn.setDigit(count);
        isbns.push_back(aisbn);
        count++;
    }
    filein.close();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc > 0)
    {
        if(argc != 2)
        {
            cout << "Error: the num of arguments should be 2";
            exit(0);
        }
    list<isbn> code;
    extIsbn_in_file(code, argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "invalid number of argument!! \n";
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Just guess the codes below drag the segmentation fault error. and not sure constructors where i set up is correct. If wrong, how can i fix it up?

```
    while(!filein.eof())
    {
        filein.getline(contents, '\n');
        cout << contents << '\n';
        aisbn.setCode(contents, count);
        aisbn.setDigit(count);
        isbns.push_back(aisbn);
        count++;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger to isolate the precise part causing the segfault ?

Comment: Debuggers can help you see where segmentation faults occur.

Comment: As a programmer, the first thing you should do when you get a crash (which is what segmentation fault is) is to run your program in a debugger. It will tell you _where_ the crash is, let you see and walk up the call-stack to your code, and also let you examine variables to see what might have caused the crash.

Comment: Also, don't do `while(!filein.eof())`! The `eof` flag will not be set until _after_ an input operation fails, so you will loop one iteration to much. Instead do e.g. `while (filein.getline(...))`.

Comment: you need to initialize the `char *contents;` to some memory allocated on heap

Comment: Refer [this](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html). It is good.

Comment: And a last thing, I recommend you use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of pointers. Pointers are the number one cause of crashes.

Comment: @weima Or use `std::string`. By the way, you should put that as an answer.

Comment: like this?         while(filein.getline(contents, 13, '\n'))
   {
    cout << contents << '\n';
    aisbn.setCode(contents, count);
    aisbn.setDigit(count);
    isbns.push_back(aisbn);
    count++;
   }

Comment: There's so much wrong in your code. **Don't use unnecessary pointers!** `std::string` not `std::string*`, `std::string` not `char*`. The `isbn* current` and `isbn* next` pointers look a bit strange too, what is that supposed to achieve? If you are trying to make a linked list, use `std::list<isbn>`. You are making programming more difficult than it needs to be. Just get rid of the pointers and then ask how to solve any further problems.

Comment: thanks your sincere advices :) will keep in mind

Answer (score 1):

Tip: `filein.getline(contents, '\n');` does not do what you expect it to do. I don't give entire solution intentionally, it would not help you learn, but instead read: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/

Comment: like this? filein.getline(contents, 13, '\n');

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialize the char *contents; to some memory allocated on heap . or use std:: string.
thanks @Jaochim